# Kodi no longer starting on RPi4 (xbian) after update

Tags: raspberry-pi, kodi, init

After updating my system, yesterday kodi no longer starts up on my raspberri pi 4 (xbian).

There seems to be an issue initing the windowing system, but I have yet been unable to figure out what the issue is precisely. Some logs that can be helpful:

cat .kodi/temp/kodi.log

```
2021-12-06 07:13:38.653 T:2812     INFO <general>: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
2021-12-06 07:13:38.653 T:2812     INFO <general>: Starting Kodi (19.3 (19.3.0) Git:20211122-b398a41951-dirty). Platform: Linux ARM 32-bit
2021-12-06 07:13:38.653 T:2812     INFO <general>: Using Debug Kodi x32 build
2021-12-06 07:13:38.653 T:2812     INFO <general>: Kodi compiled 2021-11-22 by GCC 10.2.1 for Linux ARM 32-bit version 5.10.24 (330264)
2021-12-06 07:13:38.653 T:2812     INFO <general>: Running on BCM2711 with XBian 1.0 (knockout), kernel: Linux ARM 32-bit version 5.10.75+
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: FFmpeg version/source: 15.0a2-Isengard-24792-gb398a41951-kodi-4.3.2-Matrix-19.2
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: Host CPU: ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l), 4 cores available
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: ARM Features: Neon enabled
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/local/share/kodi
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/local/lib/kodi
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: special://xbmcbinaddons/ is mapped to: /usr/local/lib/kodi/addons
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/xbian/.kodi/userdata
2021-12-06 07:13:38.713 T:2812     INFO <general>: special://envhome/ is mapped to: /home/xbian
[...]
2021-12-06 08:13:39.781 T:2864     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:39.788 T:2864     INFO <general>: No Devices found - retry: 4
2021-12-06 08:13:41.292 T:2864     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:41.300 T:2864     INFO <general>: No Devices found - retry: 3
2021-12-06 08:13:42.804 T:2864     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:42.811 T:2864     INFO <general>: No Devices found - retry: 2
2021-12-06 08:13:44.315 T:2864     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:44.322 T:2864     INFO <general>: No Devices found - retry: 1
2021-12-06 08:13:45.826 T:2864     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:45.833 T:2864     INFO <general>: Found 0 Lists of Devices
2021-12-06 08:13:45.834 T:2865     INFO <general>: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - initialize sink
2021-12-06 08:13:45.834 T:2865     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - Attempting to open device "default"
2021-12-06 08:13:45.837 T:2865     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:45.837 T:2865    ERROR <general>: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - failed to initialize device "default"
2021-12-06 08:13:45.837 T:2865    ERROR <general>: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - no sink was returned
2021-12-06 08:13:45.837 T:2864    ERROR <general>: ActiveAE::InitSink - returned error
2021-12-06 08:13:45.844 T:2812     INFO <general>: CKeyboardLayoutManager: loading keyboard layouts from special://xbmc/system/keyboardlayouts...
2021-12-06 08:13:45.868 T:2812     INFO <general>: Raspberry PI firmware version: Dec  1 2021 11:41:51
                                                   Copyright (c) 2012 Broadcom
                                                   version be18b6271a0f99f896fc81249da5da6658422558 (clean) (release) (start_x)
2021-12-06 08:13:45.868 T:2812     INFO <general>: ARM mem: 704MB GPU mem: 320MB MPG2:0 WVC1:0
2021-12-06 08:13:45.868 T:2812     INFO <general>: cache.memorysize: 20MB
2021-12-06 08:13:45.868 T:2812     INFO <general>: Config:
                                                   arm_freq=1500
                                                   audio_pwm_mode=514
                                                   camera_auto_detect=-1
                                                   config_hdmi_boost=5
                                                   core_freq=500
                                                   core_freq_min=200
                                                   disable_commandline_tags=2
                                                   disable_l2cache=1
                                                   disable_overscan=1
                                                   disable_splash=1
                                                   display_hdmi_rotate=-1
                                                   display_lcd_rotate=-1
                                                   dvfs=3
                                                   enable_gic=1
                                                   force_eeprom_read=1
                                                   force_pwm_open=1
                                                   framebuffer_ignore_alpha=1
                                                   framebuffer_swap=1
                                                   gpu_freq=500
                                                   gpu_freq_min=250
                                                   init_uart_clock=0x2dc6c00
                                                   initial_turbo=3
                                                   lcd_framerate=60
                                                   mask_gpu_interrupt0=1024
                                                   mask_gpu_interrupt1=0x10000
                                                   max_framebuffers=2
                                                   over_voltage_avs=-23750
                                                   pause_burst_frames=1
                                                   program_serial_random=1
                                                   total_mem=4096
                                                   hdmi_force_cec_address:0=65535
                                                   hdmi_force_cec_address:1=65535
                                                   hdmi_ignore_cec_init:0=1
                                                   hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:0=0x11e1a300
                                                   hdmi_pixel_freq_limit:1=0x11e1a300
2021-12-06 08:13:45.868 T:2812     INFO <general>: Config:
                                                   decode_MPG2=0x00000000
                                                   decode_WVC1=0x00000000
                                                   device_tree=-
                                                   overlay_prefix=overlays/
                                                   hdmi_cvt:0=
                                                   hdmi_cvt:1=
                                                   hdmi_edid_filename:0=
                                                   hdmi_edid_filename:1=
                                                   hdmi_timings:0=
                                                   hdmi_timings:1=
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812     INFO <general>: RetroPlayer[PROCESS]: Registering process control for GBM
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812     INFO <general>: RetroPlayer[RENDER]: Registering renderer factory for OpenGLES
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812    ERROR <general>: CDRMUtils::OpenDrm - no drm devices found: (No such file or directory)
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812    ERROR <general>: CWinSystemGbm::InitWindowSystem - failed to initialize Atomic DRM
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812    ERROR <general>: CDRMUtils::OpenDrm - no drm devices found: (No such file or directory)
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812    ERROR <general>: CWinSystemGbm::InitWindowSystem - failed to initialize Legacy DRM
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812    ERROR <general>: CDRMUtils::OpenDrm - no drm devices found: (No such file or directory)
2021-12-06 08:13:45.984 T:2812    ERROR <general>: CWinSystemGbm::InitWindowSystem - failed to initialize off screen DRM
2021-12-06 08:13:46.186 T:2812    FATAL <general>: CApplication::CreateGUI - unable to init windowing system
2021-12-06 08:13:46.186 T:2812     INFO <general>: Stopping player
2021-12-06 08:13:46.186 T:2812     INFO <general>: Storing total System Uptime
2021-12-06 08:13:46.186 T:2812     INFO <general>: Saving settings
2021-12-06 08:13:46.195 T:2812     INFO <general>: Saving skin settings
2021-12-06 08:13:46.337 T:2865     INFO <general>: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - initialize sink
2021-12-06 08:13:46.338 T:2865     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - Attempting to open device "default"
2021-12-06 08:13:46.340 T:2865     INFO <general>: CAESinkALSA - Unable to open device "default" for playback
2021-12-06 08:13:46.340 T:2865    ERROR <general>: CAESinkALSA::Initialize - failed to initialize device "default"
2021-12-06 08:13:46.341 T:2865    ERROR <general>: CActiveAESink::OpenSink - no sink was returned
2021-12-06 08:13:46.341 T:2864    ERROR <general>: ActiveAE::InitSink - returned error
2021-12-06 08:13:46.453 T:2812     INFO <general>: Stopping all
2021-12-06 08:13:46.457 T:2812     INFO <general>: stop dvd detect media
2021-12-06 08:13:46.458 T:2812     INFO <general>: Application stopped
2021-12-06 08:13:46.658 T:2812     INFO <general>: unload skin
2021-12-06 08:13:46.659 T:2812     INFO <general>: Unloaded skin
2021-12-06 08:13:46.659 T:2812     INFO <general>: unload sections
```

sudo cat /var/log/upstart/xbmc.log.1

```
Dec 06 07:04:40: ERROR: Unable to create GUI. Exiting
start: Job failed to start
stop: Job has already been stopped: xbmc
start: Job failed to start
Dec 06 07:13:46: ERROR: Unable to create GUI. Exiting
start: Job failed to start
stop: Job has already been stopped: xbmc
```

---

**UPDATE**

It seems like it was one of the following upgrades that triggered the problem:
sudo cat /var/log/apt/history.log

```
sudo apt install linux-image-bcm2836:armhf=5.10.75+-1635267102 linux-libc-dev:armhf=5.10.75-1635267102 xbian-package-repo:armhf=20210901-0 xbian-package-firmware:armhf=9.5-1610486159

Start-Date: 2021-12-02  10:53:37
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d
Upgrade: linux-image-bcm2836:armhf (5.10.75+-1635267102, 5.10.82+-1638386491)
End-Date: 2021-12-02  10:54:10

Start-Date: 2021-12-02  10:54:18
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d
Upgrade: linux-libc-dev:armhf (5.10.75-1635267102, 5.10.82-1638386491)
End-Date: 2021-12-02  10:54:22

Start-Date: 2021-12-02  10:54:29
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d
Upgrade: xbian-package-repo:armhf (20210901-0, 20211201-0)
End-Date: 2021-12-02  10:54:33

Start-Date: 2021-12-04  08:09:37
Commandline: /usr/bin/unattended-upgrade -d
Upgrade: xbian-package-firmware:armhf (9.5-1610486159, 10-1638559289)
End-Date: 2021-12-04  08:09:45
```

Comment: What update did you do? Was it security patches or a major OS release?

Comment: Actually, automatic updates from xbian are enabled. This was no major OS release.

Comment: I added details about the updates done.  (found the right log file)

I downgraded some packages and ended up with a working system again. Did not investigate yet which of these was the culprit.